# How do I use both contain and cover background image in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, image, rendering

So I have something like this :

```
        return (
            //set mushroom forest background, make it fill screen
            <div className="App" style={ {
                backgroundImage: `url(${pools})`,
                backgroundPosition: 'center',
                backgroundSize: 'contain, cover',
                backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
            }}>
```

I want to use both cover and contain for my background image, but it seems to choose 1 and render with it rather than applying both.

But when I render it with react, the image isn't stretched to the page. It only seems to pick up the first of either contain or cover, and use that for rendering the image. Anyone know how to make a background image do both contain and cover in react? The syntax I have there works just fine in its CSS equivalent.

I'm really trying to assign two values to a CSS style in react, using the syntax and have it work. Right now it either fills the whole page, but cuts off part of the image, or leaves white space on the sides but displays the whole image. I've found CSS tutorials using both cover and contain at the same time, is there some special syntax I need to use in react or JavaScript to make this work?

I've tried putting two styles into an array, using two strings such as `['contains', 'cover']` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Edit: Figured out a way around it, not sure if you can do this double value assignment thing is css at all, think I was mostly misreading a guide to doing something.

Comment: Are you using ImageBackground in react native to achieve this? Can you share your react-native code?

Comment: @ShivanshSingh No, I'm just using the CSS background-image functionality, and I am on regular react, not native. Also though I figured it out, css doesnt actually let you use multiple values for attributes, I was looking at an example that was using inline stuff to apply two different values to two separate images. I was also trying to force the image to always only stretch and not cut things off, but I'm not sure if that is easily possible. I found a solution for my program by changing the background-position to bottom, so the thing I want in the image always is. Thx for commenting though!

Comment: Contain and cover are two different things. I can't see what having both could look like. Contain will ensure the whole image is seen, leaving space either at the sides or top/bottom if needed. Cover will ensure the whole element is covered, cutting off bits of the image at top or bottom of sides as needed. Neither distorts the image. I can't understand what effect you are trying to achieve. Could you explain some more?